# How to get logits as neural network output

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Simple and short question. I have a network (Unet) which performs image segmentation. I want the logits as the output to feed into the cross entropy loss (using pytorch). Currently my final layer looks as so:

```
class Logits(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, 
                 in_channels, 
                 n_class
                 ):
      super(Logits, self).__init__()

      # fully connected layer outputting the prediction layers for each of my classes
      self.conv = self.add_module('conv_out', 
                        nn.Conv2d(in_channels, 
                                  n_class, 
                                  kernel_size = 1
                                  )
                       )
      self.activ = self.add_module('sigmoid_out', 
                        nn.Sigmoid()
                       )
```

Is it correct to use the sigmoid activation function here? Does this give me logits?

Comment: To clarify, are you doing *multi-class classification* or *multi-label classification*?

Comment: Multi-class. I have a background class and an object class and each pixel of the image should be labeled with one of the two classes. I realize now that using sigmoid as my activation function was likely an unwise choice for this.

Comment: So an input image can have multiple classes, correct?

Comment: @SteveAhlswede Since each pixel can be one of only 2 classes this is binary classification problem, not a multi-class problem. Segmentation is always multi-label since each pixel has a label. Segmentation is sometimes multi-class, specifically when there are more than 2 possible classes for each pixel. Shai's answer currently addresses the multi-class problem and Ivan's answer addresses the binary problem. Due to the spatial nature of segmentation it's also reasonable to use other losses like DICE loss or boundary loss.

Comment: Yes I was planning to try playing with different loss functions (Dice, focal loss, ect).

Answer (score 3):

When people talk about "logits" they usually refer to the "raw" `n_class`-dimensional output vector. For multi-class classification (`n_class` > 2) you want to convert the `n_class`-dimensional vector of raw "logits" into a `n_class`-dim *probability* vector.
That is, you want `prob = f(logits)` with `prob_i >= 0` for all `n_class` entries, and that `sum(prob)=1`.
The most straight forward way of doing that in a differentiable way is to use the [Softmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Softmax.html#torch.nn.Softmax) function:

```
prob_i = softmax(logits) = exp(logits_i) / sum_j exp(logits_j)
```

It is easy to see that the output of `softmax` is indeed a `n_class`-dim probability vector (I leave it to you as a short exercise).

BTW, this is why the raw predictions are called "logits" because they are kind of "log" of the output predicted *probabilities*.

Now, it is customary *not* to explicitly compute the softmax on top of a classification network and defer its computation to the loss function, e.g. [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) that *internally* computes the softmax and requires the *raw* logits as inputs, rather than the normalized probabilities. This is done mainly for numerical stability.

Therefore, if you are training a multi-class classification network with `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` you do not need to worry at all about the final activation and simply output the raw logits from your final conv/linear layer.
Most importantly, do **not** use `nn.Sigmoid()` activation as it tends to have saturated gradients and will mess up your training.

Comment: I guess what I really wanted to know was what are the 'raw' logits. As I was indeed curious what type of output I should be feeding to the ```nn.CrossEntropyLoss``` function. So if I understand correctly, if I plan to use ```nn.CrossEntropyLoss``` then I should remove the ```self.activ``` from my above class and just feed the output from the ```self.conv``` layer to the loss function?

Comment: @SteveAhlswede exactly.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you are working on a multi-label classification task where a single input can have several labels, hence your usage of `nn.Sigmoid` (vs `nn.Softmax` for multi-class classification).

There a loss function which combines `nn.Sigmoid` and the `nn.BCELoss`: [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html). So you would have as input, a vector of logits whose length is the number of classes. And, the target would as well have the same shape: as a multi-hot-encoding, with `1`s for active classes.

Comment: I don't think the OP meant multi-label task.